# Eliminar valores duplicados de un array en powerbuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

Tengo el siguiente array:

`array = {'1', '2', '1', '3'}`

Y necesito quitar los duplicados, en este caso el duplicado es el '1', y debe quedar asi:

`array = {'1', '2', '3'}`

Script:

`int  i
string array[]
array = {'1', '2', '1', '3'} 
for i = 1 to upperbound(array) 
    // array[i] 
next`

Comment: recorre el arreglo y con un condicional  si array1[i] != array2[i] asignas a un arreglo temporal el numero algo como tmp[] = array1[i]

Comment: @Bryro array1 seria mi array original y array2? Que funcion cumple?

Comment: Sorry ley mal la pregunta aqui un ejemplo http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ce190c0e6a1ce61103e560b13aacd1692b163628 en php pero la logica es la misma!